# Exporting methodcalls to file

Tags: ruby

I'm fairly new to ruby and wanted to know if it's possible to export a method/method call. 
Basically, I have this:

```
class B
  def initialize
    @bptimer = BP_Timer.new("MyName", method(:sayhello))
  end

  def sayhello()
    msgbox("hello")
  end
end

class BP_Timer
  def initialize(name = nil, method = nil)
    @name = name
    @time = 0
    @repeats = 0
    @start_from = 0 
    @method = method
    @active = false
  end

  def start()
    @active = true
    $timers.push(self)
  end
end
```

(I removed all the rather uninteresting parts of the code)

Basically, I now have a "BP_Timer" object with the name and method that will later be pushed into a **$timers** array which I want to save to a file and later on load from when I restart the program. Is it possible to deconstruct the object in such a way that I can store and restore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how we usually store/restore the state. The common approach would be to store a configuration and perform the whole initialization again.

That said, you are to store an array of *initialization parameters*, like `["MyName", :sayhello]` in your case to _YAML`,`JSON`, or any other text format of your choice:

**config.yml**

```
bp_timers:
  - "MyName": :sayhello
```

And then on program start you do:

```
config = YAML.load_file("config.yml")
config["bp_timers"].each do |k, v|
  BP_Timer.new(*[k, method(v)]).start
end
```

---

Answering your initial question: yes, this is possible to some extent with [`Marshal`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Marshal.html) class.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It's certainly looks like a way cleaner approach than mine. Can I ask a small follow up question to your answer? From what I see, you're handing over the :sayhello without any reference to a "B" object. When I load it, how does it know it's the method sayhello of class b? Or does it check all classes until it finds a method "sayhello"?

Comment: No it does not. I have just shared how the proper approach looks like, it’s not a ready-to-go snippet. You should modify it according to your needs. `B.instance_method(v)` could work, or like.